# 「私には手伝わせるつもりはないらしい。」 Who is the agent of つもりはない?

Tags: meaning

> 父は兄や姉にも店を手伝わせている。しかし、私には手伝わせるつもりはないらしい。

What does the last part つもりはないらしい。 mean? Is it the son that does not want to do it, or is it the dad not wanting to tell the son to do it?

Comment: I've mentioned this in a previous question of yours, but it would help to put your question in the title, not just the full sentences you are asking about.

Comment: @Leebo ok yes sure, sorry about that.  I will make it more clear in the title in the future

Answer (score 2):

> 父は兄や姉にも店を手伝わせている。しかし、私には手伝わせるつもりはないらしい。

To break down:

私に -- me
は -- contrastive は (contrasting 兄や姉に vs 私に)
手伝わせる -- have (me) help
つもりはない -- have no intention
らしい -- seems

私 is the object of the causative 手伝わせる, so the subject should be 父.

> "It seems that Dad has no intention to have me help."

---

> Is it the son that does not want to do it, or is it the dad not wanting to tell the son to do it?

It's the latter. To say the former, it should use the verb 手伝う, as in 私には**手伝う**つもりはない "I have no intention to **help**." Also, using らしい for the first person's intention would sound weird.